# How do I rewrite this method but as recursive

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

Write a recursive method that performs the same operation as the loop in the method shown

```
public class new1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new1(4);
    }

    public static void new1(int n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.print("-");
            --n;
            new1(n);
            System.out.println();
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                System.out.print("!!!");
                System.out.print("-"); // space dash space
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already recursive, no?

Comment: `new1(n);` is recursive.

Comment: In fairness to the OP, the question is completely clear. It's the title that's misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replaces the loop by a recursive method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new1(4);
}

public static void new1(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.print("-");
        --n;
        new1(n);
        System.out.println();
        loop(n);
    }

}

static void loop(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.print("!!!-");
        loop(n - 1);
    }
}
```